# @Style is incompatible with attribute theme (attr) reference

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

[image]
Que tal amigos, me gustaría preguntarles acerca de este error, ya llevo 3 días buscando acerca de este error buscando otros formas de solucionandolo, instalando paquetes entre otras cosas pero no encuentro nada, si lo modifico me sale que no se encuentra el Style y lo si lo dejo como lo tengo me marca el error, realmente no se que hacer, algunos me recomendarían pasarme ha android studio pero no se manejar Java ni Kotlin es por eso mismo que manejo con visual studio con C#

Editado:

```
<style name="SplashTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light"> 
<item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/Splash</item> 
<item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item> 
</style>
```

Comment: Como tenes configurado el style donde definis el splash? Lindo consejo te dan de pasarte de lenguaje y IDE por un error.

Comment: <style name="SplashTheme"
     parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
  <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/Splash</item>
  <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
 </style>

Comment: jajajajaj si lo se, por eso mismo no quisiera cambiar, pero ya en casos mas extremos pues me vería obligado a hacerlo, no se si ha esta parte te referías del splash

Comment: Te marca error en la linea 16, pero no la estas mostrando a esa linea.

Comment: En la 16 es esta <intent-filter> creo es por eso mismo que no se exactamente cual es el error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En tu proyecto encontre 3 problemas que resolvi.

1-Tenias los nuget diferentes en App, iOS y android. los dejes a los 3 con la misma version.

2-Llamabas a tu archivo SplashScreen.xml, este estaba agregado a tu carpeta pero no incluido en el proyecto.

3-El splash lo agregue dentro del tema que carga Android.

```
<style name="MainTheme" parent="MainTheme.Base">
  </style>
  <!-- Base theme applied no matter what API -->
  <style name="MainTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!--If you are using revision 22.1 please use just windowNoTitle. Without android:-->
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <!--We will be using the toolbar so no need to show ActionBar-->
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <!-- Set theme colors from https://aka.ms/material-colors -->
    <!-- colorPrimary is used for the default action bar background -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">#2196F3</item>
    <!-- colorPrimaryDark is used for the status bar -->
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#1976D2</item>
    <!-- colorAccent is used as the default value for colorControlActivated
         which is used to tint widgets -->
    <item name="colorAccent">#FF4081</item>
    <!-- You can also set colorControlNormal, colorControlActivated
         colorControlHighlight and colorSwitchThumbNormal. -->
    <item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>

    <item name="android:datePickerDialogTheme">@style/AppCompatDialogStyle</item>

    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/SplashScreen</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    <!--<item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>-->
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">true</item>

  </style>
```